# Cordova Ionic logout and refresh controllers

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I've been struggling quite some time with an ionic app.  I have multiple controllers, multiple html pages.

Whenever I log off (I use the controller of the sidemenu) I want to return to the first page. Whenever I am on the first page I want to be able to login a different user. Whenever I enable cache:false in the UI-router of the target view (menu.landingMenu) it simply won't go to that page after the logout.

This is the code for the logout.

```
 $scope.logOff = function () {

    appData.clear();
    $http.get(appData.hostURL + '/api/Account/logoff.aspx');
    $scope.$destroy();
    $localStorage.$reset();
    CredentialService.del();
    $state.go('login', { action: 'logoff' });
    $timeout(function () {
        $ionicHistory.clearCache();
        $ionicHistory.clearHistory();
    }, 1500)

}
```

This is the event in the loginController

```
 // Check if a state change happened
    $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess',
        function onStateSuccess(event, toState, toParams, fromState) {
            console.log(fromState);
            console.log('This is the Fromstrate'), fromState;
            console.log(toParams);
            if (toState.name == "login") {
                if (toParams.action == "logoff") {
                    // keep startup url (in case your app is an SPA with html5 url routing)
                    var initialHref = window.location.href;

                    function restartApplication() {


                        // Show splash screen (useful if your app takes time to load
                        // Reload original app url (ie your index.html file)

                        console.log("THis is a reload")
                        document.location.href = 'index.html';
                    }

                    restartApplication();
                } else {
                    var storedCreds = CredentialService.get()

                }
            }
        }
    );
```

First of all, whenever I logout, and I press the submit button on the page of the login, it "refreshed" the page, it blincks shortly but does not react.

Whenever I click it a second time, it goes to the next page but wont reload the controller, thus rendering no data.

Answer (score 3):

There are several things to improve or refactor in the code.

- In a single page app you don't want to refresh the page, always find a way to clean the state, cache, etc. So avoid using window.location to switch between views to reset the app.
  Use the clean functions you have to reset the state like:
  localStorage.clear();
  CredentialService.del();
  etc.
- Avoid destroyig the scope manually while it's executing a function and try to work around the cache: false that does it automatic.
- Clear the ionicHistory and cache when entering the login or index view instead of inside the logOff function.
- If needed, use the ionic events to execute functions: $ionicView.beforeEnter, $ionicView.beforeLeave, etc. http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/
- Chain promises to follow an order if possible.

Your $scope.logOff could look something like:

```
$scope.logOff = logOff;
function logOff() {
    $http.get(appData.hostURL + '/api/Account/logoff.aspx')
         .then(clearDataAndLeave);
         .catch(someErrorFunction)
}
function clearDataAndLeave(){
    appData.clear();
    $localStorage.$reset();
    CredentialService.del();
    //other cleaning actions
    $state.go('login');    
}
```

And in you login/index controller:

```
$scope.$on("$ionicView.beforeEnter", activate);
function activate(event, data){
    $ionicHistory.clearCache();
    $ionicHistory.clearHistory();
    //Then you can handle the credentials, asking if they were deleted or something like that
    var storedCreds = CredentialService.get();
    if (storedCreds){
        //login or sthg else
    }
});
```

Comment: The biggest problem I have is whenever I log back in, the controller from menu.landingMenu won't "restart" will this help? Ill try this in 2 days and will report back. Thank you !